# How to autenticate properly in Java

Tags: authentication, java, salt

I have to write some login module for Java EE application.

Previously i was using `JBoss security` - provided login and password, called `HttpServletRequest` with login method and `JBoss security` did the magic. That authentication uses Hash - `SHA`.

Right now i'm thinking about salting passwords. I have got `jbcrypt` library. It provides hashing and checking. But i dont know (mayby yet:) ) how to use it with `HttpServletRequest`.

And that leads to question what if i simply hash password, and compare it in code with `hashedPassword.equals(databasePassword)`? Is it bad option comparing to `JBoss security`?

I want to use `BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed)` and it can tell me if password is  matched. Can i do that in code or it is better to use `HttpServletRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off not rolling your own on this. People that are good at it have been building such features into frameworks and libraries. Here are two that cover that and more:

OWASP Enterprise Security API
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI#tab=Home

HDIV
http://www.hdiv.org/

OWASP also offers a wealth of knowledge on web security in general. You can also google for their section on handling passwords if you intend to roll your own anyway. They'll tell you the good and bad from registration to storage to recovery.